# Put Bookmarklet into web pages

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet code that starts with:

```
*javascript:var%20nodeaddpath="http://www..................*
```

and ends with:

```
*bout:blank"==l?nourl():a();;void(0);*
```

i didn't write to codes between start and end as they were not needed to write. Now i want to insert this bookmarklet to other web pages i.e html pages that appears like a link that when visitors click on it, it exactly works as when its on the bookmark bar of browser. I read many tutorials in stackoverflow and other websites but as they were not step by step, i couldn't use them.
Please explain all details for me step by step as i am very new in programming that i can insert this bookmarklet to webpages.

Comment: Does this question involve Java at all? If not, I will be more than happy to remove the Java tag from your question. You are of course familiar with the difference between Java and JavaScript, right?

Comment: If you're just putting it in a link, you can just put the entire thing in the `href` attribute. `<a href="javascript:var......">Link text</a>`

Answer (score 2):

A bookmarklet, as far as I know, is just a piece of JavaScript. You program it in a way as if it existed and executed on the page. In other words, write it as if it's just a normal piece of script.

Bookmarklets on the page do not differ from the bookmarklets that are run from the bookmarks bar. They are just "post-processed" JavaScript run via the address bar.

And so, given a bookmarklet script of:

```
javascript:(function(){alert('hi');}());
```

You can embed it in the page like:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){alert('hi');}());">Say Hi!</a>
```

Try dragging the link to the bookmarks bar and click it there, it does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks but in this example you wrote alert('hi'). My bookmarklet code is about 4 lines. Should i place all of this 4 lines instead of hi ? Also my bookmarklet is a code only, should i make a .js file for it? if its required, how should i do this? Please explain step by step with more details as i am newbie.

Comment: @Janemor you should use a compressor to compress your script before rolling out the final code for production. There are a lot of them on the net. Also, yes you can have a very short bookmarklet script that loads an external JavaScript that contains the actual operational code. This gives you better control of your script and users will always have an updated version of your bookmarklet operation without having them update the bookmarklet that they have.